# How to handle a website with ChromeDriver if takes ages to load?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Im trying to create a script which tests https://www.mail.com/int/ but the website seems to take ages to load (The load bard 'circle' never seems to stop), I have added page load timeouts, but it seems to be taking longer than expected to load, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: We can't make a site we don't control load faster so I'm not sure what your question is. Please clarify and show the code you have tried to solve the problem along with any other relevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed it is slow. When inspecting in the Developer Tools > Network, it takes ~30 secs to load due to GIFs and other data heavy requests.
[image]

You should use `WebDriverWait` to handle such cases:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
boolean pageLoaded = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("return document.readyState")).equals("complete");
System.out.println("Page has loaded? " + pageLoaded);
```

The above seemed to work for me. Try it and let me know.

Comment: @gbru Please accept the answer if the code works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [explicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) until the element(s) that you want to test load.

You didn't specify a language, so I assumed C#.

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    driver.Url = "https://www.mail.com/int/";
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement")));
}
```